# Connection error using pyodbc for netezza

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, netezza

I am trying to connect to a netezza server. This is the code I have

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=<Server name>;PORT=<no>;DATABASE=<dbname>;UID=user_id;PWD=password;DSN=NZSQL")

print("Connection complete")
```

My odbc.ini file is:

```
[NZSQL]
Driver32=C:\windows\SysWOW64\nsqlodbc.dll
[ASTEST]
Driver32=C:\windows\SysWOW64\cwbodbc.dll
[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
NZSQL=NetezzaSQL (32 bit)
ASTEST=iSeries Access ODBC Driver (32 bit)
ASPROD=iSeries Access ODBC Driver (32 bit)
[ASPROD]
Driver32=C:\windows\SysWOW64\cwbodbc.dll
```

My odbcinst.ini file is:

```
[IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - TACOM32 (32 bit)]
Driver=C:\PROGRA~2\QUESTS~1\TOADDA~1.2\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLI.DLL
Setup=C:\PROGRA~2\QUESTS~1\TOADDA~1.2\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2ODBC.DLL
32Bit=1
[ODBC 32 bit Drivers]
IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - TACOM32 (32 bit)=Installed
MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver (ToadDataPoint3.8) (32 bit)=Installed
[MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver (ToadDataPoint3.8) (32 bit)]
Driver=C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Toad Data Point 3.8\Plugins\MySQL\ODBC\lib\myodbc5.dll
Setup=C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Toad Data Point 3.8\Plugins\MySQL\ODBC\lib\myodbc5S.dll
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] Client unable to establish connection (12) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I don't understand this error. Is this a netezza error or is my connect statement wrong? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Did you made entry for `NetezzzaSQL` in `odbc.ini` file?

Comment: No I have not. What do you mean by make an entry?

Comment: When you mention `DRIVER={NetezzaSQL}`, it reads the configuration from the entry from the `odbc.ini` file for the mentiuoned driver. Check this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.netezza.use.doc/topics/configuring_nzodbc_linuxfile.html

Comment: The entry already exists. I tried following the link. I will spend some more time on it. But that is for Linux or Unix right? I am using windows. Thank you.

Comment: In Windows I believe it is easier. But I think configuration will remain the same, location of the files just might differ. I do not have any idea for it on windows machine

Comment: Thank you.! If I use the same credentials on excel to establish a connection, It works fine. Will continue working on it. :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: The connectionstrings.com entry [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/netezza/) says to use `servername=`, `username=`, and `password=`, not `SERVER=`, `UID=` and `PWD=`. Also, omit the `DSN=` parameter if you are already supplying the `Driver`, `servername`, `port`, and `database`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a server issues. When python was trying to connect to the server, it had some issue. The same code worked fine the next day. It did say client unable to establish connection.